# new django/python user having issues with __init__ i've defined a few classes, and want to use one class as a field for another

Tags: python, django

I'm a new django user and am confused by some features of inheritance and instantiation, particularly making a field of a type class that is user defined.

When I try to add an artist from the admin page i get
python TypeError: **init**() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'website', and 'instagram' [18/Jul/2017 21:43:28] "GET /admin/showyourwork/artist/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 110559

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
from django.db.models import ImageField
from django.urls import reverse


class Artist(models.Model):
    # Fields
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    name = models. CharField(max_length=61, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

    # Metadata
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["last_name", "first_name"]

    # Methods
    def __init__(self, name, first_name, last_name, website, instagram):
        self.name = name
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.website = website
        self.instagram = instagram

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular instance of MyModelName.
        """
        return reverse('model-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the MyModelName object (in Admin site etc.)
        """
        return self.name


class Media(models.Model):
    # Fields
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)

    # Metadata
    # class Meta:
    #    ordering = ["author", "title"]

    # Methods
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.artist = Artist(None, None, None, None, None)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular instance of MyModelName.
        """
        return reverse('model-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the MyModelName object (in Admin site etc.)
        """
        return self.title

class Picture(Media):
    # Fields  inherits title and author from Media
    image = ImageField()

    # Metadata inherits from Media

    # Methods
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image = kwargs.pop('image')
        super(Media, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Series(Media):
    # Fields  inherits title and author from Media
    images = []

    # Metadata inherits from Media

    # Methods
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.images.append(kwargs.pop('image'))
        super(Media, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def addimage(self, image):
        self.images.append(self, image)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be overriding the `__init__` method from django.model.Model.
If you need something like that, the documentation can guide you on how approach this issue:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model

Comment: thank you! now i need to figure out how to deal with the series which is an array of pictures, which is now working thanks to you!

Comment: In this case, shouldn't you be using `ForeignKey`?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Yep you're definitely right there!  thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied, please accept the answer so the question is not 'unanswered' anymore ;)

Comment: This works, but I can't find an option to add a Picture that is already in the database.  The admin site forces me to create a new Picture.  I'd like to be able to have the same picture in many series as well.